# How to convert string to mm/dd/yyyy format

Tags: vb.net

How do I change a string like "15:33:56 Thursday 17th, November 2016" to mm/dd/yyyy date format. I have already tried to use the inbuilt VB.NET date function `CDate()`

Comment: Googled "vb.net date tryparse" and the first result was https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ch92fbc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. It would be worth showing the code you have in place.

Comment: @muffi - Based on the quesion, I doubt the OP knows to look for the term "TryParse", but I agree a simple search should have been tried first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code that works for the date you gave as an example.

```
Dim str As String = "15:33:56 Thursday 17th, November 2016"

'Remove the "th" from "17th, since this confuses the parser
str = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(str, "[a-z]{2}(?=,)", String.Empty)

'change the date to mm/dd/yyyy format
str = DateTime.Parse(str).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
```